# How do I take accessories off my slimes?

Tags: slime-rancher

The 4.1 update introduced [fashionable accessories](http://images.akamai.steamusercontent.com/ugc/107355924084652675/D307B89B51E2A760EADBDA2E419ABB9C9EA67A88/) that can be put on slimes. While I absolutely love them, I'd also like to take them off without having to get rid of the entire slime. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update 0.4.2 has introduced the Fashion Pod Remover, which lets you remove fashion pods from normal, largo and gordo slimes. Sucking up slimes in your Vacpack is still an effective way of removing fashion pods, as well.

Answer (score 2):

To remove accessories from your slimes, the only way is to suck them up into your Vacpack, and then to shoot them out. You will then get your accessories back.

Do note that this only applies for normal slimes. For [Largo slimes](http://slimerancher.wikia.com/wiki/Largo_Slimes), there is currently no way to remove the accessories from them.